# WPF DataBinding propertychanged event is not fired

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public string Box { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public Item ScanningItem 
    {
        get
        {
            return _scanningItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _scanningItem = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("ScanningItem");
            if (AddItemCommand !=null)
                AddItemCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

View:

Problem: change value in the textbox, the PropertyChanged event of Item-->ScanningItem will not be fired.

in MVVMLight, there is a feature that Model can notify ViewModel if got PropertyChanged, anyone know how to use that feature?

Comment: Which property are you binding in the textbox? Post your xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned a TextBox, presumably you're binding to a Property of your object. This will not work because you haven't changed the instance of the object only the value of a property.

You have two options in this situation, you can expose the properties individually and fire the PropertyChanged event. Alternatively you could implement INotifyPropertyChanged within the model.

**ViewModel**

```
public string SerialNo
{
    get { return _scanningItem.SerialNo; }
    set
    {
        _scanningItem.SerialNo = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SerialNo");
    }
}
```

Comment: and in the view, instead of binding to ScanningItem.SerialNo, i should bind to SerialNo?

Comment: not sure whether you are familiar with MVVMLight,  it has the ability to notify ViewModel the PropertyChange of View from View,  any idea?